# why is it showing failed to converge?

Tags: python, machine-learning, seaborn, logistic-regression

i am getting this error while processing for titanic dataset as I was implementing logistic regression. I cannot resolve the issue.

```
    ConvergenceWarning: lbfgs failed to converge (status=1):
```

STOP: TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT.

Increase the number of iterations (max_iter) or scale the data as shown in:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html
Please also refer to the documentation for alternative solver options:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression
n_iter_i = _check_optimize_result(
LogisticRegression()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that you need to increase your maximum iterations.
I will show you where

```
class sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', max_iter=100)
```

Increase your `max_iter` to let's say `1000` and try running ur model.

Also, make sure your data is scaled because `LogReg` does not work well when your data has lots of scale difference between columns.

Answer (score 0):

In case of mine, even after changing the *max_iter* to *1000000* didn't work. so, I changed the solver from *lbfgs* to *liblinear* and it worked.

```
LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')
```